# Angularjs passing object to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Angular newbie here. I am trying to figure out what's going wrong while passing objects to directives.

here's my directive:

```
app.directive('walkmap', function() { 
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    scope: { walks: '=walkmap' },
    template: '<div id="map_canvas"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
      console.log(scope);
      console.log(scope.walks);
    }
  };
});
```

and this is the template where I call the directive:

```
<div walkmap="store.walks"></div>
```

`store.walks` is an array of objects.

When I run this, `scope.walks` logs as `undefined` while `scope` logs fine as an Scope and even has a `walks` child with all the data that I am looking for.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here because this exact method has worked previously for me.

EDIT:

I've created a plunker with all the required code: http://plnkr.co/edit/uJCxrG

As you can see the `{{walks}}` is available in the scope but I need to access it in the link function where it is still logging as undefined.

Comment: Can you post plunker/jsfiddle example where your code does not work. I've create plunker with absolutelly same code as in your question and it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/TKVVDXp0m9jnVSRYBxVp?p=preview May be problem with some other part or your code?

Comment: what the the context of store.walks, have u defined store.walks in parent scope if not you have to define store.walks in either local scope or parent scope

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since you are using `$resource` to obtain your data, the directive's link function is running before the data is available (because the results from `$resource` are asynchronous), so the first time in the link function `scope.walks` will be empty/undefined.  Since your directive template contains `{{}}`s, Angular sets up a `$watch` on `walks`, so when the `$resource` populates the data, the `$watch` triggers and the display updates.  This also explains why you see the walks data in the console -- by the time you click the link to expand the scope, the data is populated.

To solve your issue, in your link function `$watch` to know when the data is available:

```
scope.$watch('walks', function(walks) {
   console.log(scope.walks, walks);
})
```

In your production code, just guard against it being undefined:

```
scope.$watch('walks', function(walks) {
  if(walks) { ... }
})
```

**Update:** If you are using a version of Angular where `$resource` supports promises, see also @sawe's answer.

Comment: That most certainly works. Thanks so much for explaining the asynchronous nature of $resource. I had a feeling that might be the issue, but because `{{walks}}` kept rendering in the template that through me off.

Comment: there is a parenthesis/bracket that should be deleted :) `scope.$watch('walks'), function(walks) {` to `scope.$watch('walks', function(walks) {`

Comment: Updated / complete Plunker with Mark Rajcok's answer here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ed2Wqv?p=preview.

Note that you need to open your browser's (eg. Firefox Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools) console in order to see the console.log(scope.walks);
output and thus 'witness' the completed working directive populated asynchronously from the resource data - top work - thanks a million Mark!

Comment: Note that `$resource` depends on `$http` which call asynchronously the success and error functions. So if you use the lower level `$http` you are just the same situation and will need the aid of `$watch`.

Answer (score 12):

you may also use

```
scope.walks.$promise.then(function(walks) {
    if(walks) {
      console.log(walks);
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is good because it will wait for the async call to resolve before updating the directive scope

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to add `ControllerAs` to the directive by which you can access the directive's variables.

```
app.directive('walkmap', function() { 
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    controllerAs: 'dir',
    scope: { walks: '=walkmap' },
    template: '<div id="map_canvas"></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
      console.log(scope);
      console.log(scope.walks);
    }
  };
});
```

And then, in your view, pass the variable using the `controllerAs` variable.

```
<div walkmap="store.walks" ng-init="dir.store.walks"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<div walk-map="{{store.walks}}"></div>

angular.module('app').directive('walkMap', function($parse) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      console.log($parse(attrs.walkMap)(scope));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, not sure what the (scope) does, was able to get it to work with $parse(attrs.walkMap)()

Answer (score 0):

your declared $scope.store is not visible from the controller..you declare it inside a function..so it's only visible in the scope of that function, you need declare this outside:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource, ClientData) {
  $scope.store=[];         // <- declared in the "javascript" controller scope
  ClientData.get({}, function(clientData) {
  self.original = clientData;
  $scope.clientData = new ClientData(self.original);
  var storeToGet = "150-001 KT";
  angular.forEach(clientData.stores, function(store){
   if(store.name == storeToGet ) {
     $scope.store = store;      //declared here it's only visible inside the forEach
     }
   });
  });
 });
```

Comment: Just tried that and it makes no difference. The `{{walks}}` is available in the directive template, that's why you can see all the data, but it's not available in the link function.